# BackEnd для сайта

Tags: python, backend

Начинаю изучать написание сайтов, если с фронтом все еще более менее понятно и даже готов фронтэнд, то вот с бэком возникли сложности.

С чего начать писать, если хочу написать его на питоне? БД уже написана, но как настроить связи между кнопками, формами на сайте с бд? Как написать небольшую админ панель? Пользоваться вордпрессом нет желания, потому что в моем понимании- это костыль.

Comment: Могу подкинуть пару статей для изучения клиент серверного взаимодействия:
- [https://habr.com/ru/articles/495698/](https://habr.com/ru/articles/495698/)
- [https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/Server-side/First_steps/Client-Server_overview](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/Server-side/First_steps/Client-Server_overview) Сам я их полностью не читал, но статьи должны быть неплохие.

Comment: Простой бэк - `Flask`. А если всякие админ панели нужны, то может лучше в сторону `Django` начинать смотреть, там готового всего полно.

Answer (score 1):

Для новичка стоит использовать веб сервер Flask, он простой и довольно быстрый. Чтобы связать форму на сайте в теге `form` необходимо прописать `action` - адрес по которому будут отправляться данные и метод, в большинстве случаев лучше использовать `POST`:

```
<form action="/action_page.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="John"><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Doe"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

А в веб сервере Flask нужно создать Route с методом POST:

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/form', methods=['POST'])
def index():
    print(request.form.get("fname"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Учи Django, достаточно удобный фреймворк, почти всё есть из коробки, туториалов на ютубе куча. Если хочешь запариться и писать всё руками, то можно и без фреймворков это всё делать). А WP - просто удобная для заказчика cms, ему там всё просто и понятно, но на пыхе